# Finicky external monitor with hobbled 2013 MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, display, thunderbolt, hdmi

Hi so I have an early 2013 retina MacBook Pro that has very much seen better days.  The lcd broke long ago due to a closing-the-laptop-with-something-still-inside accident; and because this was the very first MBP that required the retina screen, it was always too expensive to fix it.  To get it to work I’ve been connecting it to an external monitor through the laptop’s HDMI port.

Recently though there was a water spillage accident that occurred, and now the internal keyboard doesn’t work properly (well more specifically, it seems to cause the power button to think it’s being pressed down constantly so the thing just boot loops infinitely).

Okay so no problem there, I just disconnected the internal keyboard ribbon like I had disconnected the internal monitor ribbon.  I bought a wired USB keyboard and mouse to plug in and should be no problem.

And here is the thing: I am able to get it to work-sometimes—but for some reason now the external monitor thing is REAL finicky.  Sometimes I will turn the thing on and plug everything in and I have to mess around for like ten minutes before the laptop finally gets the clue that I want it to use the external monitor that it’s plugged into.

Does anyone know why this would be so difficult? Often it requires me unplugging and plugging in the cable many times.  I’ll try powering on and off a bunch of times.  It always eventually works; but so far I haven’t identified any one particular thing that clues the computer in that, yaknow, “use the damn external monitor like you always do, please?”

Any thoughts would be helpful.  It’s an early 2013 MBP with the internal keyboard ribbon and internal monitor connection severed.  I use the hdmi port to hdmi input on the monitor, but I also have a thunderbolt2hdmi cable that Ill sometimes use through the MbP’s thunderbolt port to try and cycle through options when the hdmi2hdmi isn’t working.

Comment: Given what you have done to it, time for a replacement.

Comment: You have a liquid damaged machine - why do you think the damage was limited to the keyboard and not to other components like the logic board?

Comment: jeez, coming back on this three years in the future, really gives a good impression of the friendliness of this particular stack exchange board. What made you think that I didn't think that the prior liquid damages weren't also potentially causing the other issue? I was asking for some thoughts/ideas as to which direction the issue might be coming from so I could fix it.  I don't see anywhere in there that I said "where on earth could these problems be coming from on my like-new condition laptop!?"  My finances were tough due to being in a difficult times, thanks though for the helpful advice.

Comment: What Allan was pointing out is the simple fact that the water spillage caused more issues than just with the keyboard, and might very well also have impacted the part of the logic board which handles the external monitor. This basically makes the question unanswerable as such.

Comment: @nohillside @nohillside♦ Okay.. but where in my question did I say I didn't think liquid damage was the cause of the problem?

And how does it make the question "unanswerable as such"? Liquid damage isn't some magic potion that causes computers to fail in entirely non-specific, unknowable ways. As I mentioned in the question, I've remedied consequences of the spill for the power button and keyboard. I was looking for some help identifying which other component might now be failing, based on the symptoms described. How do you justify saying that makes the question unanswerable?

Comment: Seems more like he wanted to pad his comment numbers by answering more questions, but without actually adding anything of value, instead dropping an unhelpful, snarky, and dismissive comment to someone who clearly didn't have the money to buy a brand new laptop and was looking for help fixing an entirely fixable macbook pro.

Comment: The simple answer to why the "external monitor thing is REAL finicky" is "because there is a hardware damage of some kind". You could try another cable or another port, but if the problem persists it's either with the monitor or the motherboard.